# How to assign values to x1+x2, x1x2?

Tags: assignment

```
x1 + x2 = -((2 a^2 k m)/(b^2 + a^2 k^2))
```

Enter the above content and an error prompt will pop up

[image]

How to assign values to x1+x2, x1x2?

Comment: `x1 + x2 == -((2 a^2 k m)/(b^2 + a^2 k^2))` which is to say that you can write equations, but cannot assign since you don't have a variable on the LHS.

Comment: What is it you actually want to achieve?

Comment: In future calculation steps, adding or multiplying these two quantities can automatically be carried into the subsequent values for calculation

Answer (score 1):

## Use == instead of =

See [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) for examples of `=`.  The expression `x1+x2` cannot be set, it's similar to writing `5=xyz`.  Numbers cannot be assigned a value, neither can expressions composed of `+` or `/` or other math symbols.

The way to write a *proposition* in Mathematica is with `==`, see [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html).  This is more inert: `x1+x2==abc` is valid, so is `5==xyz`.  They are suitable for use with [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) and [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html).

## The question as posed

Technically, it is possible to "assign" a value to x1+x2.  Instead of defining DownValues with =, we can define UpValues of x1 with [`TagSet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html):

```
x1 /: x1 + x2 = -((2 a^2 k m)/(b^2 + a^2 k^2))
```

Then every instance of `x1` (even in non-matching expressions) will be checked if it is followed by `+x2`.  This is not a good use of `/:` in my opinion.

## Extras

Note that `x1x2` is not the same as `x1*x2` nor `x1 x2`.  The former is a variable which is entirely unrelated to `x1` and `x2`, the latter are both ways to write the product of the variables.

Comment: In future calculation steps, adding or multiplying these two quantities can automatically be carried into the subsequent values for calculation